# IExceptionHandlerPathFeature returns null when calling a controller-action when user's role authorization isnt fullfilled

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When a logged in user request the access to an action method where doesnt meet the minimum required  role it the error action method returns a null object from  IExceptionHandlerPathFeature, it doesnt really change anything if it runs  on development,staging or production also I noticed when I tried to use default exception pages the exception page returned was blank, now I had to use custom exception pages to avoid this, I am not sure if this is related somehow

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        private IConfiguration _config;

        public Startup(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {   options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 2;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()/*.AddDefaultTokenProviders()*/;




            services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("EmployeeDBConnection")));                                                   
            services.AddMvc(options=> 
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            }).AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
            //services.AddSingleton<IEmployeeRepository, EmployeeRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IEmployeeRepository, SQLEmployeeRepository>();
            services.AddSingleton<IDepartmentRepository, DepartmentRepository>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {

                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(new DeveloperExceptionPageOptions()
                {
                    SourceCodeLineCount = 0,
                });
            }
            else
            {

                //app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}").UseMiddleware<ErrorController>("/Error/{0}");
                //app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/");
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc(route =>
            {
                route.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            });
            app.UseStaticFiles();






        }
    }
```

ErrorController.cs

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment;
        private readonly ILogger<ErrorController> logger;
        public ErrorController(IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment, ILogger<ErrorController> _logger)
        {
            logger = _logger;
            hostingEnvironment = _hostingEnvironment;
        }
        // GET: /<controller>/
        [Route("Error/{statusCode}")]
        public IActionResult HTTPCodeStatusHandler(int? statusCode)
        {
            if (statusCode != null && (((int)statusCode) >= int.MinValue && ((int)statusCode) <= int.MaxValue))
            {
                if (hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    return View($"~/Views/shared/error{statusCode}.cshtml");
                }
                else
                {
                    var statusCodeResult = HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();
                    if (statusCode == 404)
                    {
                        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Sorry, the page you have requested cannot be found";
                        if (statusCodeResult != null)
                        {
                            //ViewBag.Path = statusCodeResult.OriginalPath;
                            //ViewBag.QS = statusCodeResult.OriginalQueryString;
                            logger.LogWarning($"404 Error ocurred.Path :{((statusCodeResult.OriginalPath is "/") ? "/Home": statusCodeResult.OriginalPath )} And Query String {((statusCodeResult.OriginalQueryString is null) ? "/Home":statusCodeResult.OriginalQueryString) }");
                        }
                        return View($"~/Views/shared/error{statusCode}.cshtml");
                    }
                }
                return View();
            }
            return Error();
        }
        [Route("Error")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            var exceptionDetails = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();

            logger.LogError($"The path {exceptionDetails.Path} threw andexception {exceptionDetails.Error}");


            ViewBag.ExceptionPath = exceptionDetails.Path;
            ViewBag.ExceptionMessage = exceptionDetails.Error.Message;
            ViewBag.StackTrace = exceptionDetails.Error.StackTrace;

            return View("~/Views/shared/Error.cshtml");
        }
    }
```

Comment: How did you get into Error method with 403 status code?I could not get into the Error method but return the default AccessDenied.cshtml.For Identity would redirect to AccessDenied page without any exception.You could custom middleware to custom the exception message.

Comment: I never got into Error HTTPCodeStatusHandler but in Error IActioNResult, but for some reason the redirection is not working for me because AccessDenied page isnt the one which redirects instead go tot the error controller and shows exceptionDetails = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>(); as null. How Would I why redirection (To Access denied Action)on Identity is not working properly? I see i could modify the Authorize attribute but. I wonder why when creating an ASP NET core 2.2 project from blank is throwing to the error controller

Comment: @Rena Configuring the Application cookie's default AccessDenied path helped to fix the problem I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure the cookies AccessDenied Path option that solved the issue

```
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => 
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/AccessDenied");
            });
```